# Trying to inject a table, rows, and cells using CoffeeScript via Google Closure Library

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript, google-closure

I am struggling trying to inject a table, rows, and columns into an HTML page using coffeeScript and google closure library. If I can't get it done in coffeeScript then I suppose I can revert to jQuery or javaScript straight up, so some direction in code for that is welcome as well.

The documentation is not very helpful for the goog closure library, and I am relatively new to coffeeScript. Also half of the commands for google closure library is deprecated or cryptic.

Any help would be appreciated, following is the current HTML, desired HTML, followed by the coffeeScript.

Anyhow here is the HTML:

```
<div id="propertiesContainer" class="propertiesContainer" style="visibility: visible; left: 954.7777862548828px; top: 50.989585876464844px;">
 <div class="propertyEditor">
   <label>label</label>
   <input type="text">
 </div>
 <div class="propertyEditor">
   <label>size</label>
   <input type="text">
 </div>
</div>
```

I want the HTML to look like:

```
   <div id="propertiesContainer" class="propertiesContainer" style="visibility: visible; left: 954.7777862548828px; top: 50.989585876464844px;">
    <div class="propertyEditor">
     <table>
     <tr>
       <td><label>label</label></td>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>  
    <div class="propertyEditor">
    <table>
     <tr>
       <td><label>size</label></td>
       <td><input type="text"></td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

The coffeeScript currently looks like:

```
render: (parent) ->
    @title = goog.dom.createDom 'label', null, goog.dom.createTextNode(@name)
    @input = goog.dom.createDom 'input', {'type': 'text'}, null
    container = goog.dom.createDom 'div', {'class': 'propertyEditor'}, @title, @input
    goog.dom.appendChild parent, container
return
```

Comment: then sans all the invalid embedded divs

Comment: alright, the HTML should be valid now, now some suggestions?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the div `propertiesContainer` is the `parent`? If it is, then the code as written is creating divs of class `propertyEditor` and adding a `<label>` and an `<input>` node to that before appending the whole thing to the parent. Which is the output you call "current HTML" - If you are hoping to get tables then the coffeescript code needs to be changed to create them. If I have made an incorrect assumption please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

So far, by using the third-to-nth argument to `goog.dom.createDom`, you have accomplished adding  one level of children to a node. This is the JSdoc for it:

- `@param {...(Object|string|Array|NodeList)} var_args` Further DOM nodes or strings for text nodes. If one of the `var_args` is an array or *NodeList*, its elements will be added as childNodes instead.

To create additional levels of child nodes, you can provide two types of value as the third argument of `createDom`:

1. Use (possibly nested) arrays to express the node hierarchy;
2. Provide a previously created Node or NodeList of arbitrary DOM hierarchy (output with `goog.dom.createDom` or any other method that produces a *Node* or *NodeList*).

Here's a minimal implementation of what you want to accomplish, based on your code:

```
###* @constructor ###
Dummy = ->
  @name = 'some name'
  return

Dummy.prototype =    
  render: (parent) ->
    @title = goog.dom.createDom 'label', {}, @name  # *1*
    @input = goog.dom.createDom 'input', {'type': 'text'}
    table = goog.dom.createDom 'table', {}, [       # *2*
      goog.dom.createDom 'tr', {}, [
        goog.dom.createDom 'td', {}, @title
        goog.dom.createDom 'td', {}, @input
      ]
    ]
    container = goog.dom.createDom 'div', {'class': 'propertyEditor'}, table
    goog.dom.appendChild parent, container

# initialization
dummy = new Dummy
dummy.render goog.dom.getElement 'propertiesContainer'
```

see it working on [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexndl/N9FTD/4/).

**Notes:** (numbered in the code block above)

1. Since `@name` is a string, it's not mandatory to wrap it in a text node beforehand. `goog.dom.createDom` will apply the needed conversion (stated by JSDoc)
2. An array as the third argument can express arbitrarily complex DOM hierarchies. If you look to invest in Closure Tools and this sort of operation is too repetitive or error-prone with complex DOM, consider [Closure Templates](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/) as an alternative.